# How to align content horizontally

Tags: html, css, alignment, block

I'm super new here, so apologies in advance for this question...

I'm trying to create 3 blocks of text but align them horizontally. I don't want to create buttons, just block of text.

This HTML doesn't seems to work

```
<div id="boxes">
    <h1>EFFICIENT</h1>
    <p>Each part of the budget is spent programmatically with a performance objective</p>

    <h1>TAILORED</h1>
    <p> Each campaign is different and tailored to our clients needs</p>

    <h1>DEDICATED</h1>
    <p>Our team is fully dedicated to our client with a personalised approach and daily contacts</p>
</div>
```

and the CSS

```
#boxes {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
   }

#boxes h1 p {
float: left;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```css
      #boxes {
    height: 90px;
    border: 2px dotted #ee944d;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
          padding:15px;
  }
  
 #boxes h1 p {
   float: left;
   text-align:left;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>

<body>
   <div id="boxes">
  <h1>EFFICIENT</h1>
  <p>Each part of the budget is spent programmatically with a performance objective</p>

  <h1>TAILORED</h1>
  <p> Each campaign is different and tailored to our clients needs</p>

  <h1>DEDICATED</h1>
  <p>Our team is fully dedicated to our client with a personalised approach and daily contacts</p>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but it just enframed the content without align it horizontaly...);

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way to do this:

```css
#boxes {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 300px;
}

#box {
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div id="boxes">
  <div id="box">
    <h1>EFFICIENT</h1>
    <p>Each part of the budget is spent programmatically with a performance objective</p>
  </div>

  <div id="box">
    <h1>TAILORED</h1>
    <p> Each campaign is different and tailored to our clients needs</p>
  </div>

  <div id="box">
    <h1>DEDICATED</h1>
    <p>Our team is fully dedicated to our client with a personalised approach and daily contacts</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I changed the codes it doesn't work unfortunately; still aligned vertically..

Comment: Can you share a snippet of the changes?

Answer (score 0):

Inside the style for boxes just add 
display: inline...

```
#boxes{
display: inline;
}
```